# XDebug is not present in phpinfo on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php

### Heading

I am having an issue with setting XDebug to work with my php5;
The core problem seems to be that XDebug cannot be shown in my phpinfo.

Env:
Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.4.5

here is what i tried with xdebug.

xdebug installation: 
sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
then an xdebug.so is installed in the following location.
/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so

```
file /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

then i appended the following settings into the php.ini file being referenced by phpinfo in my apache.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so

; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_autostart = Off
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

BTW, i had restarted my apache server many times, but no luck, the xdebug was still not present in my php info.

please correct my steps if inappropriate and any  advice and clues that can help resolve my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can install xdebug http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Comment: Not sure if this *really* matters but when I've installed XDebug, the `zend_extension` line went **before** `[xdebug]` (which is also all lowercase)

Comment: Also, `apt-get` should have added a config file in `/etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini`.

Comment: @NanheKumar, thanks, but according to the official install doc, the cmd "# pecl install xdebug" should be performed, on my ubuntu this command returns "pecl/xdebug is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.2.3
install failed". I believe xdebug is really installed on my machine;

Comment: @Phil, thanks, i modified my php.ini according to your suggestion, it did not work. I was wondering about your last comment with xdebug.ini....should this one be placed somewhere.... BTW, /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini only has one line: zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so

Comment: It looks like i have another php 53 on the same machine, the xdebug seems to be able to be detected with that php (with the command php -m, the xdebug is shown right in the end), but with php 54, the xdebug cannot be detected. (i.e. xdebug is not shown with ./php -m )....

Comment: I guess the problem may have something to do with the other php installed in the same box. It seems that the other php is working fine with the xdebug, but the one i want to work with is not working. I was wondering if there a way or neccessary steps to be taken to correlate the xdebug with the php?

Answer (score 2):

I executed the following command and it worked again on an updated Ubuntu 14.10

```
sudo php5enmod xdebug
```

Everything was right on the php5-xdebug package but the module wasn't enabled for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution to my problem, it seems my problem has something to do with the other php installed in the same box, i rebuilt the xdebug with the php i want to use, then i let the php.ini reference the newly built xdebug.so, the problem went away, i was able to view the xdebug information in phpinfo. With "apt-get install php5-xdebug", the xdebug is compiled with the other php which i dont want to use.

I believe this information can be useful to those who have the same problem.

To troubleshoot, make sure you can find xdebug under the zend extension in the list returned by the cmd "php -m"; Try to verify the zend api version with php -i | grep 'zend', and this has to be the same as the one being used to build the xdebug.so.

I am quite sure i have seen a FAQ in the xdebug official website that is quite related to my problem.

Anyway, thanks to those who have commented on my problem, especially Phil, your last comment is a bit enlightening.